# Why does it keeps on calling for tiger.name? Even tho I entered letter B which is for tiger.animal_type it shows the answer but with the tiger.name

Tags: python, if-statement, python-class

Keeps on calling for `tiger.name` but I only asked for `tiger.animal_type`:

[image]

Comment: Please paste the code here

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value